# If $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions, does $A^Tx=b$ also have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation, transpose

$A$  is a real $n\times n$ matrix. If $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions, does $A^Tx=b$ and $b\not=0$  also have infinitely many solutions? I can't think of a counterexample.

Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you want $b \neq 0$? In that case $A = 0$ is an easy counter example.

Comment: If $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $b=(0,1)$, then...

Comment: @E.Ginzburg If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solution this means that A is singular that is $rank(A)<n$ and thus also $rank(A^T)<n$.

Therefore $A^Tx=b\neq0$ has **infinitely many solution or no solution**.